# Python ошибка библиотеки telegram.ext.filters import

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу телеграм-бота, но при импорте возникла ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Person\Desktop\bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext.filters' (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\filters.py)
```

Вот мои импорты:

```
import os
import datetime
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import defaultdict
```

В чем проблема? может кто подскажет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filters напишите с маленькой буквы
[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#module-telegram.ext.filters)